# My Visual Studio ASP.NET Project Keeps Adding A Release Configuration After I Delete It

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution that contains a ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 project. Within the configuration manager, I have removed the default Debug and Release configurations for both the solution and project and replaced them with 3 configurations of my own, none of which are named Debug nor Release. Every time I reopen the solution, I repeatedly see a Release configuration added to the ASP.NET MVC project, even after attempting to delete it several times and verifying that it doesn't exist in the raw markup of the .sln and .csproj files. The Release configuration also appears to be blank.

Is this a known bug with Visual Studio? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I believe studio adds configs based on the build project (debug/release/etc)

Comment: @Vince I agree, however, I removed all build definitions for debug and release that I could find in both the .sln and .csprof files.

Comment: Sorry, if you go into configuration manager under active solutions drop down click edit, you should be able to remove them from there.  If that isn't working, I'm not entirely sure why.